# Using meshgrid to convert X,Y,Z triplet to three 2D arrays for surface plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d

I'm new to Python so please be patient. I appreciate any help!

**What I have:** three 1D lists (**xr, yr, zr**), one containing x-values, the other two y- and z-values
**What I want to do:** create a 3D contour plot in matplotlib

I realized that I need to convert the three 1D lists into three 2D lists, by using the **meshgrid** function.

Here's what I have so far:

```
xr = np.asarray(xr) 
yr = np.asarray(yr)
zr = np.asarray(zr)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xr,yr)
znew = np.array([zr for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = znew.reshape(X.shape)
```

Running this gives me the following error (for the last line I entered above):

```
 total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I went digging around stackoverflow, and tried using suggestions from people having similar problems. Here are the errors I get from each of those suggestions:

Changing the last line to:

```
Z = znew.reshape(X.shape[0])
```

Gives the same error.

Changing the last line to:

```
Z = znew.reshape(X.shape[0], len(znew))
```

Gives the error:

```
Shape of x does not match that of z: found (294, 294) instead of (294, 86436).
```

Changing it to:

```
Z = znew.reshape(X.shape, len(znew))
```

Gives the error:

```
an integer is required
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have proper size? Basically, you have to have `nx` as length of `xr`, `ny` as length of `yr`, and `nx*ny` as length of `zr`

Comment: Basically, look at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/meshgrids-and-disambiguating-rows-and-columns-from-cartesian-coordinates/

Answer (score 1):

Well,sample code below works for me

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xr = np.linspace(-20, 20, 100)
yr = np.linspace(-25, 25, 110)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xr, yr)

#Z = 4*X**2 + Y**2

zr = []
for i in range(0, 110):
    y = -25.0 + (50./110.)*float(i)
    for k in range(0, 100):
        x = -20.0 + (40./100.)*float(k)

        v = 4.0*x*x + y*y

        zr.append(v)

Z = np.reshape(zr, X.shape)

print(X.shape)
print(Y.shape)
print(Z.shape)

plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def get_data_for_mpl(X, Y, Z):
    result_x = np.unique(X)
    result_y = np.unique(Y)
    result_z = np.zeros((len(result_x), len(result_y)))
    # result_z[:] = np.nan

    for x, y, z in zip(X, Y, Z):
        i = np.searchsorted(result_x, x)
        j = np.searchsorted(result_y, y)
        result_z[i, j] = z

    return result_x, result_y, result_z


xr, yr, zr = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

plt.contourf(*get_data_for_mpl(xr, yr, zr), 100)
plt.show()
```

**Detailed answer**

At the beginning, you need to find out for which values of `x` and `y` the graph is being plotted. This can be done using the `numpy.unique` function:

```
result_x = numpy.unique(X)
result_y = numpy.unique(Y)
```

Next, you need to create a `numpy.ndarray` with function values for each point `(x, y)` from `zip(X, Y)`:

```
result_z = numpy.zeros((len(result_x), len(result_y)))

for x, y, z in zip(X, Y, Z):
    i = search(result_x, x)
    j = search(result_y, y)
    result_z[i, j] = z
```

If the array is sorted, then the search in it can be performed not in linear time, but in logarithmic time, so it is enough to use the `numpy.searchsorted` function to search. but to use it, the arrays `result_x` and `result_y` must be sorted. Fortunately, sorting is part of the `numpy.unique` method and there are no additional actions to do. It is enough to replace the `search` (this method is not implemented anywhere and is given simply as an intermediate step) method with `np.searchsorted`.

Finally, to get the desired image, it is enough to call the `matplotlib.pyplot.contour` or  `matplotlib.pyplot.contourf` method.

If the function value does not exist for `(x, y)` for all `x` from `result_x` and all `y` from `result_y`, and you just want to not draw anything, then it is enough to replace the missing values with NaN. Or, more simply, create `result_z` as numpy.ndarray` from NaN and then fill it in:

```
result_z = numpy.zeros((len(result_x), len(result_y)))
result_z[:] = numpy.nan
```