# How does matlibplot.contour work in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been studying python and matplotlib. And I found the following sample code, but I couldn't understand how contour works in the code. I think in plt.contour(X, Y, Z), X and Y are mesh points, Z is the height of each point. But I can't figure out why the output is like the figure below. Can anyone tell me why those colorful lines are output?(based on what does contour draw the lines?) And is there a similar function for 3D output?

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

matplotlib.rcParams['xtick.direction'] = 'out'
matplotlib.rcParams['ytick.direction'] = 'out'

delta = 0.025
x = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, delta)
y = np.arange(-2.0, 2.0, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
Z2 = mlab.bivariate_normal(X, Y, 1.5, 0.5, 1, 1)
# difference of Gaussians
Z = 10.0 * (Z2 - Z1)


# Create a simple contour plot with labels using default colors.  The
# inline argument to clabel will control whether the labels are draw
# over the line segments of the contour, removing the lines beneath
# the label
plt.figure()
CS = plt.contour(X, Y, Z)
#plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.clabel(CS, inline=1, fontsize=10)
plt.title('Simplest default with labels')

plt.show()
os.system("pause")
```

[image]

Comment: Contour draws lines of constant Z value. You can control the spacing of the lines, but by default contour looks at your Z data and helpfully chooses some values that give a few visible contours.

Comment: That might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34126136/using-meshgrid-to-convert-x-y-z-triplet-to-three-2d-arrays-for-surface-plot-in-m/